# Stream video on Android

Tags: iphone, android, http, video, streaming

I have a video stream that I used in an iPhone application. I'm now working to port the application to Android so I want to use the same stream.

As Apple requiered, I created a HTTP Live Streaming (media segmenter, m3u8 file, etc.). You can find the stream here: http://envue.insa-lyon.fr/smartphone/aloun_stream/prog_index.m3u8 .

I want to use this same stream on Android. Did someone have the same a resembling experience?

Comment: Either I'm on a cutting-edge problem or nobody gives a damn about Android... :-?

Comment: Wondering the same question, there no mention in the official Android docs, so it looks like it's not supported...

Comment: On Android you have to fall back to Android solutions, I guess the Apple standard wont fit. Just use .flv video streaming like everyone else :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on the m3u8 stream. I just used mp4-s with android-streaming capabilities.

Comment: It's not obvious to create this type of media. The surest way is with HandBrake (Mac) by checking "Web optimized"

Answer (score 2):

Honeycomb/Android 3.0 has limited support for HLS.  Anything before that does not have built in support, but there are supposed to be third party SDKs that will do it, but searching shows a lot of people that can't ge a hold of the third party dev.

Check the Android dev docs to find out what is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use webscoket to continuously get TS files as Apple defines, and send to a player to decode the H.264+AAC within TS packet

Comment: Hey Clone pig. I'm interested in using the m3u8 files.  Can you please expand further on how one would do this? what libraries do I need to use? do you have an example code?

Comment: In the HLS spec, the M3U8 format file actually is XML file, so you could use xml lib to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Check android 4.0 - it claims to support HTTP Live Streaming 3.0 fully, including HTTPS. For older versions I've seen some people reommening it,but haven't tried myself