# Is there a way to stream live video to android app?

Tags: android, video, streaming

I have a project where a client wants to stream his live video to a android app.  He is streaming is as asf file now.  Is there a way to stream video to android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can stream mp4 video: [Stream video on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956240/stream-video-on-android)